# Firebase @DocumentID property wrapper not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to update certain values in a specific Firebase document, however, whenever the code fires, I get the error:

[FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (7fc6c510be38) Stream error: 'Not found: No document to update: projects/htg-inspection/databases/(default)/documents/Projects/365A2F53-CB38-47A6-93C3-7D6DA14038D9

Based on the response it would seem that the Id I get back from my data struct is different from the document ID that I'm trying to update. I assumed that the @DocumentID property wrapper is supposed to solve this, or am I doing/not doing something correctly/incorrectly?

These are the corresponding DocumentIDs and what I'm getting back are some random strings (assumingly from the Swift's UUID initializer)

[image]

My Projects Data Struct:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase





struct ProjectsData: Identifiable, Codable{
    
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var client: String
    var description: String
    var inspections: [InspectionsData]

    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        
        case id
        case title
        case client
        case description
        case inspections
    }
    
}
```

Sub-Collection:

```
struct InspectionsData: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var category: Category
    var trade: String
    var inspectionDate: Date
    var dueDate: Date
    var assigned: Bool
    var location: String
    var images: [InspectionImages]
    var checklists: [ChecklistsData]
    var dateToString: String{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY "
                return formatter.string(from: inspectionDate)
    }

    var dueDateToString: String{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY "
                return formatter.string(from: dueDate)
    }
    
}

struct ChecklistsData: Identifiable, Codable{
    
    var id = UUID()
    var question: String
    var hasPassed: Bool
    var hasFailed: Bool
    var isnotApplicable: Bool
}



enum ChecklistCodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
 
    case id
    case question
    case hasPassed
    case hasFailed
    case isnotApplicable
    
    
}
```

My View Model:

```
class ProjectsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var projects = [ProjectsData]()
    @Published var inspectionData = [InspectionsData]()
    @Published var assignedProjects: [AssignedProjectsModel] = []
    @Published var retrievePhotos = [UIImage]()
    @Published var inspectionImages = [InspectionImages]()
    @Published var showImageViewer = false
    @Published var selectedImageID: String = ""
    @Published var checklists = [ChecklistsData]()
    @Published var hasPassed = false
    @Published var hasFailed = false
    @Published var isnotApplicable = false


func updateChecklist(_ checklist: ProjectsData, hasPassed: Bool, hasFailed: Bool, isnotApplicable: Bool) {
      if let documentId = checklist.id {
            db.collection("Projects").document(documentId).updateData(["checklists" : ["hasPassed" : hasPassed, "hasFailed" : hasFailed, "isnotApplicable" : isnotApplicable]]) {
                    error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Document has been updated")
                    }
                }
      }
    }

}
```

The View that I'm trying to update the database from:

```
struct ChecklistComponent: View {
    
    @State var hasPassed: Bool
    @State  var hasFailed: Bool
    @State  var isnotApplicable: Bool
    
    
    @ObservedObject var checklistvm = ProjectsViewModel()
    var documentID: ProjectsData

    
    var checklistItem: String = ""

    var question: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HeaderOne(text: question, size: 16)
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack{
                ChecklistButton(text: "Pass", textColor: hasPassed ? "#00AA97" : "#696969", buttonColor: hasPassed ? "#B0EFE8" : "#DBDBDB",
                                action: {
                    hasPassed.toggle()
                    hasFailed = false
                    isnotApplicable = false
                    checklistvm.updateChecklist(documentID, hasPassed: hasPassed, hasFailed: hasFailed, isnotApplicable: isnotApplicable)
                })
                
                ChecklistButton(text: "Fail", textColor: hasFailed ? "#AA0000" : "#696969", buttonColor: hasFailed ? "#EFB0B0" : "#DBDBDB",
                                action: {
                    hasFailed.toggle()
                    hasPassed = false
                    isnotApplicable = false
                    checklistvm.updateChecklist(documentID, hasPassed: hasPassed, hasFailed: hasFailed, isnotApplicable: isnotApplicable)
                })
                
                ChecklistButton(text: "N/A", textColor: isnotApplicable ? "#89AA00" : "#696969", buttonColor: isnotApplicable ? "#EDEFB0" : "#DBDBDB",
                                action: {
                    isnotApplicable.toggle()
                    hasFailed = false
                    hasPassed = false
                    checklistvm.updateChecklist(documentID, hasPassed: hasPassed, hasFailed: hasFailed, isnotApplicable: isnotApplicable)
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-30 ,height: 161)
        .background(.white)
        .cornerRadius(31)
    }
}
```

Of course this is a lot of code and I can't share the entire project, but hopefully this can give enough context to lend your assistance.

Using @FirestoreQuery wrapper:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

    struct HomeView: View {
        
        @State var searchable = ""
        @State var navtoView = false
        @State var showLogoutdialog = false
        @ObservedObject var homevm = HomeViewModel()
        var auth = AuthService()
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationmode
        @State var firstname = ""
        @ObservedObject var projectvm = ProjectsViewModel()
        @State var selectedProject: ProjectsData?
        @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "Projects") var projects: [ProjectsData]
    
     
        
        var body: some View {
            
            
            NavigationView{
                ScrollView(.vertical){
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .height(70)
                    HeaderComponent(firstname: users.firstName)
                    
                    SearchBar(searchText: $searchable)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                  
    
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(projects, id: \.id) { item in
                            ProjectFeedCard(projectTitle: item.title, client: item.client)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    
                                    self.selectedProject = item
                                    navtoView.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    //MARK: NavigationLinks
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination:ProjectView(inspections: selectedProject?.inspections ?? [], projectTitle: selectedProject?.title ?? "" , client: selectedProject?.client ?? "",description: selectedProject?.description ?? "", documentID: selectedProject ?? ProjectsData(title: "", client: "", description: "", inspections: []), checklists: []) , isActive: $navtoView){
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    CustomButton(action: {showLogoutdialog.toggle()}, buttonText: "Log Out", buttonColor: .accentColor)
                        .padding()
                 .confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showLogoutdialog, titleVisibility: .visible){
                        Button("Sign Out", role: .destructive){
                            homevm.logOutApp()
                            presentationmode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                 .onAppear{
                     projectvm.fetchProjects()
                 }
                    
                    
                }
                .background(Color(hexadecimal: "#F8F8F8"))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
                
                
            }
            
      
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You don’t need the UUID part firebase sets the id. You are actually breaking the decoding/encoding by trying to give it a value as you are. Those strings are not a UUID from Swift.

Comment: @loremipsum You mean remove the id variable from the ProjectsData struct? Wouldn't I need that for Identifiable Protocol?

Comment: Not the variable just the part after the = with UUID. It isn’t needed Firebase does that.

Comment: @loremipsum Ok I understand you. The funny thing is that I've tried that, as when I do, My projects array from the Foreach loop goes out of whack, in fact I get this error in the console:

 ForEach<Array<ProjectsData>, Optional<String>, ModifiedContent<ProjectFeedCard, AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture<TapGesture>>>>: the ID nil occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

Comment: The flow is a bit tricky you should only use the versions that have returned from fire base in a ForEach loop. That is when the id won’t be nil. Use the Firebase Query wrapper for the list.

Comment: @loremipsum Things are getting weird now, I tried the FirestoreQuery and nothing has appeared in my projects list. Added the code snippet in the original question

Comment: Firestore Query is really picky if there are any variables missing it just fails with no warning the “easy” way to “fix” is to make all the variables optional. Once you adopt the Firebase’s full “Custom Object” setup this isn’t an issue because the variables are decoded and encoded by firebase every step of the way. Just look at the documentation.

Comment: Tried that as well and it didn't seem to work. Not really sure what to do at this point. The only issue happening is the mismatch of the id's

Comment: Hard to tell via this website it is all about flow. The `= UUID().uuidString` part isn't correct in any setup what you see in Firebase is not a `Swift.UUID` it is an `id` generated by firebase. You are just creating a band-aid by adding that there, `FirestoreQuery` when the data is setup correctly is an easy wrapper but you can use snapshot listener instead, it is easier to find the inconsistencies there because you can implement `do try catch`. In your `getDocuments` section right now you are likely adding default values, that is why your `FirestoreQuery` isn't working.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for your help, I managed to solve the issue. I did away with the DocumentID wrapper and used a normal String and re-did my functions that fetched the data from Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the id variable to a String and re-did the fetch projects function. So in short I just completely scrapped the @DocumentID wrapper which didn't seem to work. The @FirestoreQuery query wrapper worked after I changed the ID variable in my data model, but I didn't need it again since my View Model did the job

Data Struct:

```
struct ProjectsData: Identifiable, Codable{
    
    var id: String
    var title: String?
    var client: String?
    var description: String?
    var inspections: [InspectionsData]

    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        
        case id
        case title
        case client
        case description
        case inspections
    }
    
}
```

I refactored the function that gets documents from Firestore to this:

```
func fetchFireStoreData() {
        db.collection("Projects").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error == nil {
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot{
                    
                    //Get all documents
                    self.projects = snapshot.documents.map({ document in
                        
                        let id = document.documentID
                        let title = document["title"] as? String ?? ""
                        let client = document["client"] as? String ?? ""
                        let description = document["description"] as? String ?? ""
                        let inspections = document["inspections"] as? [String : [String : Any]]
                        
                        var inspectionsArray = [InspectionsData]()
                        
                        if let inspections = inspections {
                            for inspection in inspections {
                                let categoryText = inspection.value["category"] as? String ?? "error"
                                let category = Category(rawValue: categoryText) ?? .Electrical
                                let trade = inspection.value["trade"] as? String ?? "error"
                                let inspectionDate = (inspection.value["inspectionDate"] as? Timestamp)?.dateValue() ?? Date()
                                let dueDate = inspection.value["dueDate"] as? Date
                                let assigned = inspection.value["assigned"] as? Bool ?? false
                                let location = inspection.value["inspection"] as? String ?? ""
                                let images = inspection.value["images"] as? [String : [String : Any]]
                                let checklists = inspection.value["checklists"] as? [String : [String : Any]]
                                
                                var imagesArray = [InspectionImages]()
                                var checklistsArray = [ChecklistsData]()
                                
                                
                                if let checklists = checklists{
                                    for list in checklists {
                                        let question = list.value["question"] as? String ?? "error"
                                        let hasPassed = list.value["hasPassed"] as? Bool ?? false
                                        let hasFailed = list.value["hasFailed"] as? Bool ?? false
                                        let isnotApplicable = list.value["isnotApplicable"] as? Bool ?? false
                                        
                                        checklistsArray.append(ChecklistsData(question: question, hasPassed: hasPassed, hasFailed: hasFailed, isnotApplicable: isnotApplicable))
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                
                                inspectionsArray.append(InspectionsData(category: category, trade: trade, inspectionDate: inspectionDate , dueDate: dueDate ?? Date.now, assigned: assigned, location: location, images: imagesArray, checklists: checklistsArray))
                                
                                
                                
                                if let images = images {
                                    for image in images {
                                        let url = image.value["url"] as? String ?? "error"
                                        
                                        imagesArray.append(InspectionImages(url: url))
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        self.projects.append(ProjectsData(id: id ,title: title, client: client, description: description, inspections: inspectionsArray))
                        
                        return ProjectsData(id: id, title: title, client: client, description: description, inspections: inspectionsArray )
                        
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm now able to get the correct Document ID and now I can use my updateChecklist function.